# Developer Portal API Returning 401

Tags: wso2

I am following the latest example of the products/online-store here: https://github.com/wso2/k8s-api-operator.  I generate the key through the portal and and run  "https://wso2apim:32003/store/v1.0.0/products" which returns a 401

Logs show:

```
[2020-08-05 22:39:44,698] WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[2020-08-05 22:39:45,100] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing GET request for : /store/v1.0.0/products.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.TestKeyAuthenticator.handleRequest_aroundBody4(TestKeyAuthenticator.java:76) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.7.78.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.TestKeyAuthenticator.handleRequest(TestKeyAuthenticator.java:65) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.7.78.jar:?]
at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:368) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:2.1.7-wso2v168]
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:2.1.7-wso2v168]
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:2.1.7-wso2v168]
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:2.1.7-wso2v168]
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:331) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:2.1.7-wso2v168]
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:99) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:2.1.7-wso2v168]
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:366) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:?]
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:187) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:?]
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
[2020-08-05 22:39:45,100] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe$ByteBufferInputStream.waitForData(Pipe.java:501) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:?]
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe$ByteBufferInputStream.read(Pipe.java:473) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:?]
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:205) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792) ~[commons-io_2.4.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769) ~[commons-io_2.4.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744) ~[commons-io_2.4.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.consume(RelayUtils.java:465) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:?]
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.consumeAndDiscardMessage(RelayUtils.java:485) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:?]
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.consumeInputOnException(ServerWorker.java:385) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:?]
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.handleException(ServerWorker.java:598) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:?]
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:373) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:?]
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:187) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v168.jar:?]
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

Any suggestions apreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you try this with DevPortal the request goes to the Synapse gateway and not to the microgateway. You can use the generated token from Devportal and use it to access the API using the curl command pointing to the endpoint in K8s.

```
curl -X GET "https://IP:9095/store/v1.0.0/products" -H "Authorization:Bearer $TOKEN" -k
```

If you are looking to access the API from the Devportal, then you need to expose the API in Ingress mode [1] in order to handle CORs. Then using the admin portal you can create a label and when publishing the API you can assign that label to the gateway. When you come to the devportal you can see the label along with the hostname. So you can access the API from the devportal. Sample scenario can be found in [2] related to Istio example.

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/k8s-api-operator/tree/master/scenarios/scenario-17

[2] - https://github.com/pubudu538/demos/tree/master/S06-Promote_API_from_Private_to_Public_Istio